# How to increase the speed of the below program?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the below question.

> You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray from L to R.
>
> First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries.
>
> Next line contains N space seperated integers denoting array elements.
>
> Next Q lines contain two integers L and R(indices of the array).
>
> Print a single integer denoting the answer.*

I have replaced `print()` with `stdout.write()` and `input()` with `stdin.readline()`.

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

x,y=map(int,stdin.readline().split())

array=[int(x) for x in stdin.readline().split()]

result=[]

sum=0
for i in range(y):
    l,r=map(int,stdin.readline().split())
    for i in range(l-1,r):
        sum = sum + array[i]
    result.append(sum//(r-l+1))
    sum=0

for i in result:
    stdout.write(str(i)+"\n")
```

The time taken by my code is about 8 secs, to solve the challenge time limit is 1.5 secs

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to _increase_ the speed?

Comment: I want to increase the speed or decrease the time taken to get it done in less than 1.5 secs

Comment: What about `math.floor(sum(array[l:r]))` and why store the values in `result` and not print right away? Also not sure why you start at `l-1`, did you mean `range(l, r+1)` perhaps?

Comment: There is no change in the speed of the program after implementing your suggestions. No, it from l-1 as the question assumes that the index start from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually pretty simple if you store the sums from `1-i` in the `i`th value of the array, like so:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

x,y=map(int,stdin.readline().split())

array=[int(x) for x in stdin.readline().split()]
sums[0] = array[0]
sums = [sum[i-1]+array[i] for i in range(1,len(array))]

result=[]

for i in range(y):
    l,r=map(int,stdin.readline().split())
    result.append((sums[r-1]-sums[l-1])//(r-l+1))

for i in result:
    stdout.write(str(i)+"\n")
```

By doing presummation it changes the speed of the program from O(N^2) to O(N) which should be much faster.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the append operation. It is a costly operation and is unecessary since you don't reuse the results. Instead, do directily:

```
for i in range(l-1,r):
    sum = sum + array[i]
stdout.write(str(sum//(r-l+1))+"\n")
```

By doing like this you avoid go through the second loop too.
If you try, please report here the time taken.

Comment: There is no decrease in time taken.